# python create daily folder

Tags: python, file, logging

I would like to read from the serial of RPi and store the data in a daily folder as a 'csv.' file. I can create a file, write/read to/from csv file and had the serial comm working with putty for now (tried in a different project). In the future, the comm is going to be between pi and a various sensor. Considering everything else is working I am not sure how to create a seperate file automatically for each day. This is what I've done so far;

```
import serial
import time
import csv

def readLine(port)
    rv = ""
    while True:
        ch = port.read()
        rv += ch
        if ch == '\r' or ch =='':
            return rv

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate = 115200, timeout = 10)

while True:
    rcv=readLineCR(port)

str1 = time.strftime("%d%m%y")
file = open('directory....')

with open('test.csv', 'w') as fp:
     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
     # data to be tested
     data = [[str1,'1234'],[str1,'4321']]
     a.writerows(data)
     print('csv is created on: ' + str1)

reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
print(line)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show what you have tried!

Comment: Using a python [logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) you can *easily*  create a logging system where files rotate automatically. If you skip the foldering.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @msvalkon. Creating a logging system seems a little bit advanced at the moment. But will try in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%d-%m")` to create folder name, `os.path.exists(...)` to check if folder exists and `os.mkdir(...)` to create new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @furas. this is what I did and seems like its working.

```
import os
todayDate = time.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
directory = '/home/pi/...' + todayDate
if not os.path.exists(directory)
   os.makedirs(directory)
```